# Bucketed Sink in scalaz-stream

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

I am trying to make a sink that would write a stream to bucketed files: when a particular condition is reached (time, size of file, etc.) is reached, the current output stream is closed and a new one is opened to a new bucket file.

I checked how the different sinks were created in the `io` object, but there aren't many examples. So I trIed to follow how `resource` and `chunkW` were written. I ended up with the following bit of code, where for simplicity, buckets are just represented by an `Int` for now, but would eventually be some type output streams.

```
  val buckets: Channel[Task, String, Int] = {

    //recursion to step through the stream
    def go(step: Task[String => Task[Int]]): Process[Task, String => Task[Int]] = {

      // Emit the value and repeat
      def next(msg: String => Task[Int]) =
        Process.emit(msg) ++
          go(step)


      Process.await[Task, String => Task[Int], String => Task[Int]](step)(
        next
        , Process.halt // TODO ???
        , Process.halt) // TODO ???
    }

   //starting bucket
    val acquire: Task[Int] = Task.delay {
      val startBuck = nextBucket(0)
      println(s"opening bucket $startBuck")
      startBuck
    }

   //the write step
    def step(os: Int): Task[String => Task[Int]] =
      Task.now((msg: String) => Task.delay {
        write(os, msg)
        val newBuck = nextBucket(os)
        if (newBuck != os) {
          println(s"closing bucket $os")
          println(s"opening bucket $newBuck")
        }
        newBuck
      })

    //start the Channel
    Process.await(acquire)(
      buck => go(step(buck))
      , Process.halt, Process.halt)
  }

 def write(bucket: Int, msg: String) { println(s"$bucket\t$msg") }
 def nextBucket(b: Int) = b+1
```

There are a number of issues in this:

1. `step` is passed the bucket once at the start and this never changes during the recursion.  I am not sure how in the recursive `go` to create a new `step` task that will use the bucket (Int) from the previous task, as I have to provide a String to get to that task.
2. the `fallback` and `cleanup` of the `await` calls do not receive the result of `rcv` (if there is one). In the `io.resource` function, it works fine as the resource is fixed, however, in my case, the resource might change at any step. How would I go to pass the reference to the current open bucket to these callbacks?

Comment: ok, so in the meantime I have created my own `BucketedWriter extends Writer` that I can use with `resource`, but it's pretty imperative (implementing java api).

Answer (score 0):

Well one of the options (i.e. time) may be to use simple `go` on the sink. This one uses time based, essentially reopening file every single hour:

```
val metronome =  Process.awakeEvery(1.hour).map(true)


def writeFileSink(file:String):Sink[Task,ByteVector] = ???


def timeBasedSink(prefix:String) = {
  def go(index:Int) : Sink[Task,ByteVector] = {
    metronome.wye(write(prefix + "_" + index))(wye.interrupt) ++ go(index + 1)
  }

  go(0)
}
```

for the other options (i.e. bytes written) you can use similar technique, just keep signal of bytes written and combine it with Sink.